# How to present research ideas to professor

Tags: research-process, undergraduate, research-undergraduate, supervision

I am a college freshman interested in doing neuroscientific research. After asking a professor for a collaboration, I've been told to email him my idea for a research project for him to look over. How should I present my research ideas to him? Should I write a research proposal or a quick overview of my ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it in the form that is conventional for scientific writing: the IMRaD-structure.

IMRaD is an acronym for Introduction, Methods, Results and Discussion.

**Introduction**

- What is the topic? Why is it important?
- Is there any other research tackling similar issues?
- Why are the other research findings not sufficient? What kind of 'gap' is there that your idea would try to fill? ...
- ... in other words, what is your original research aim (or: research question)?

**Method**

- What would you do (step by step) in order to answer the question?
- What materials, data, or concepts do you use? Why?
- How do you analyse the data?

**Results**

- What could you possibly find if you use the methods outlined above?

**Discussion**

- How does your result answer the research question posed in the Introduction?
- Can you speculate what led to that result?
- Why is the finding important? Does it have any practical or theoretical implications?
- What are the limitations of your study?
- What would be further research venues?

Comment: The above is good for for a post-graduate student with some training, not for an undergraduate I reckon.